# How to get property AssetName from Image.asset in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, assets

From an AssetImage object i'm trying to get the file name in Flutter.

```
 Image photo = Image.asset('assets/images/image-not-found.jpg');
 print(photo.image);           // AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/image-not-found.jpg")
 print(photo.image.assetName);  // assetName not defined
 print(photo.image.name);       // name not defined
```

How to get [this assetName](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AssetImage/assetName.html) property?

Something nicer without doing some regex on `photo.image.toString()`;

**EDIT:**

the purpose here was to retrieve the image name in order to compare it.
So i just go for direct comparaison.

```
if(photo.image == AssetImage('assets/images/image-not-found.jpg')){
  print("image was not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try AssetImage for this.

```
var photo = AssetImage('assets/images/image-not-found.jpg');
print(photo.assetName);
```

Comment: This way work, thanks, but my image was actualy from ``Image.memory`` so it will return Image type not AssetImage, i prefer to stick on it if possible.

Comment: assetName is for AssetImages . You can not get the name of Image.memory by using asset name. 
The name itself states assetName.

Answer (score 0):

//You can use split method like

`String toSplit = 'assets/images/image-not-found.jpg';

```
var imageName = toSplit.split("/");
```

print(var[2]);`

//You can get your image name stored in var[2].

Answer (score -1):

First, add an asset folder in pubspec file like:

```
assets:
   - specify a folder where is your assets are stored.
```

and use like this

```
Image.asset(
    'assets/images/profile.png',
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
),
```